# How can I convert any Cell into an Integer if possible in VBA for Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, type-conversion

I would like to create a function that will take as a parameter a `Cell` and return an `Integer`. If the conversion is not successful it should simply return 0, without throwing error messages to the user.

I don't care about the cells that contain float values, they could also return 0 since it doesn't look like integer. But text values like `00001234` should return `1234` and `12 34` should return 0.

Comment: How do you want this conversion to work? What result do you want from 3.14 for example? And what about hex strings like 0x03?

Comment: @Jean-François Yes I did try and I have many ways to avoid that.. I just wanted the right way to solve this issue..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function ConvertToInteger(Cell As Range) As Integer
   On Error GoTo NOT_AN_INTEGER
   ConvertToInteger = CInt(Cell.Value)
   Exit Function
NOT_AN_INTEGER:
   ConvertToInteger = 0
End Function
```

Note, for example, that a value of 5.6 will return 6, though. If you want it to be 0 instead, you must check for it and do accordingly.

Comment: This is as simple as it could be, just to get you started.

Comment: what about values that are over 32768?

Comment: @Jean-François  when I try to convert anything bigger than it returns an error which means 0. seems like it support only 16bit Integers.. is there any way to get something like CLong?

Comment: @Lipis get the function to return a Long and call CLong instead of CInt.

Comment: @David there is no CLong in VBA :)

Answer (score 3):

If the requirement is to return an integral number regardless of length of the input string, you could format your cell to have 0 decimal places and do something like below, which automatically promotes the data type to the precision required. Otherwise you would have to truncate the input value if you really just wanted a VBA integer.

```
Public Function ConvertToIntegral(Cell As Range) As Variant
   On Error GoTo catch
   Dim result As Variant
   result = Val(Cell.Value)
   ConvertToIntegral = result
   Exit Function
catch:
   ConvertToIntegral = 0
End Function
```

Comment: Now you might want to edit your answer to avoid any kind of infinite recursion :)